# Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка не двигалась/растягивалась при нажатии?

Tags: html, css

Есть кнопка:

```
<button id="random_test">
  <p id="text_random_button">Случайный тест</p>
</button>
```

Как в css заставить её не двигаться/растягиваться по нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: можете уточнить что именно двигается?

Answer (score 2):

Кнопка может "двигаться" и/или "растягиваться" если что то меняется в layout'e (при ее нажатии) или изменяется ее собственный размер.

На примере ниже видно что сейчас она всегда на одном месте и одного и того же размера:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  document.querySelector("p").classList.toggle("color")
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", handleClick)
```

```css
.color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>текст текст текст</p>
<button>Сменить фон текста</button>
```